# How to define $\operatorname{dim}(\{0\})$ and $\operatorname{ht}(A)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

Matsumura's "Commutative Algebra",  Chapter 5, Page 72.

It follows from the definition that

$\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p)=\operatorname{dim}(A_{\mathfrak p})\quad (\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec}(A))$,

and that, for any ideal $I$ of $A$,

$\operatorname{dim}(A/I)+\operatorname{ht}(I)\le \operatorname{dim}(A).\\$

If $I=A$, then we have $A/I=\{0\}$.

I want to know how to define $\operatorname{dim}(\{0\})$ and $\operatorname{ht}(A)$?

Comment: The height of an ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is the largest possible chain of nontrivial prime ideal inclusions, i.e., the longest possible chain of the form $\mathfrak{p}_0 \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_n := \mathfrak{p}$, where $n$ is the length of the chain. Since the ring $0$ has no prime ideals, it is natural to define $\dim 0 := -1$, as no such  chain can exist. 

On the other hand, it doesn't necessarily make sense to talk about the height of the unit ideal because it is never prime.

Comment: @Geoff $\operatorname{ht}(I)=\operatorname{inf}\{\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p)|\mathfrak p\supset I\}$, where $I$ is any proper ideal of $A$, $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $A$.